# Include a php file and call it from another php file

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have two php files

I have this setup with many php files, the problem is if I change the code in one file I have to update all files with the same change.

Is it possible to setup parameters and then call a php file with the code which basically has a lot of if's and while's in it.

I have tried include but its the other way around, in the code file I have to include the parameters file. I basically the opposite.

I have also tried to setup parameters in the first file and execute the second php file from it, but it seems the parameters set in first file are not inheriting into the second file.

a.php

```
$a=1;
$b=2;

//some code
```

b.php

```
$a=7;
$b=8;

//The same code as above.
```

Comment: why not make a function on top of the file like `function acceptVars($a,$b) {global $a; global $b;}` then when you include the file with `include_once a.php;` you can pass parameters with  `acceptVars(7,8)`

Comment: The code already has too many functions and too many loops, and its quite long, putting the whole thing in function might result unexpected outcome. I haven't tried it though, I will give it a try and revert back.

Comment: it doesnt do anything, just takes the vars you pass and set them as global so other functions can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the code that's the same into an include file, e.g. `common.php`.

`a.php`

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
include 'common.php';
```

`b.php`

```
$a = 7;
$b = 8;
include 'common.php';
```